# How to make this loop not freeze my program and consume so much cpu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

how to make this not freeze my program and consume so much cpu ..
i tried thread sleep but same

```
     while (true) 
        {

            Process[] pename = Process.GetProcessesByName("Europa_Client");
            if (pename.Length > 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }


        }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please open the game first!");

    }
```

Comment: Consider describe your problem in more detail, and provide `what you want to achieve?` in more detail also you need to describe if you really need too keep looping and check every x seconds or not

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(500)` however i fear you have bigger problems, please read the help on how to ask a good question

Comment: Instead of a while loop, use a Timer control and check for the presence of your app running there.

Answer (score 0):

Your While loop is bad, because it is meant to run forever.
You must use a Boolean variable and change it inside of the while loop. You never should write a while loop and asking while (true), because true always stays true and that's why your loop will run forever.